# Upper bound of the modulus of a complex function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

Let $R>0$ be $\underline{\text{large}}$. If $0\leq t\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, prove that $|\xi|\leq \frac{6}{R}$, where $\xi:=-\frac{2}{R}e^{-it}+\frac{4}{R^3}e^{-3it}$. As a first attempt, I can show that $|\xi|^2=\frac{4}{R^2}+\frac{16}{R^6}-\frac{16}{R^4}\cos(2t)$. However, I'm lost after this step. This is a part of a problem I found in a complex analysis book. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the assumption isn't $R\ge1$? When $t=0$ we have $\xi = \frac4{R^3}-\frac2R$ which is not less than $\frac 6R$ when $0<R<\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: May I ask which complex analysis book you got this problem from?

Comment: @GregMartin Assuming that $R$ is large is key in the problem. It's one of those Argument Principle problems. So, yes, your observation is correct. Let us work under the assumption that $R$ is 'large'.

Comment: @Clayton 'Complex Variables' by Stephen D. Fisher.

Comment: @user775349 Great—in that case, you should edit the question to include that important information.

Comment: If it’s for sufficiently large $R$, then you can work immediately from how $\xi$ is defined and show $|\xi|<3/R$ using the triangle inequality.